# Tab Bar Controller won't show Tab Bar Item in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, nstabviewcontroller

I have created a Tab Bar Controller in Swift, but the Tab Bar Item will not show up. The tab bar view controller is being opened from another view controller via a segue between the other view controller (not a UIButton, but directly from the view controller) and the tab bar view controller. I feel like this has something to do with it, but I am not sure. Here is an image of my storyboard in Xcode:

[image: My Storyboard]

Comment: you need to segue to Main TabBarController , Seems like you are connecting Segue to TabBar Controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You need Two Segues Here From Your Very First Screen

```
Segue 1 : Navigate to Get Start Screen Where submit Button is connected on click of Get Started Button

Segue 2 : Navigate to TabBarController Directly on click of Go Directly Button
```

Segues From GetStarted Screen

```
Segue 1 : Navigate to Tab Bar Controller on click of Submit Button
```

**Note**

-> You had Connected a Segue From veryFirst Screen to GetStarted Screen Thats Correct

-> From GetStarted Screen you had connected a Segue to First TabBar Screen instead of TabBar controller

**Expected Output**

**Navigate through Get Started Screen**

[image]

**Navigate Directly**

[image]